# Win32Com connection failure to Autocad via Python

Tags: python, com, pywin32, autocad, win32com

I need to connect and control AutoCAD via COM interface. For this purpose, I use Python. In my first trial with a very basic snippet<sup>(1)</sup>, I got an error. The code is:

```py
import win32com.client
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
doc = acad.ActiveDocument
doc.Utility.Prompt("Hello from Python\n")
```

and when I try to run it, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SBYSMR10\Desktop\recipe-440493-1.py", line 2, in <module>
    acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

I have Python 2.6 and AutoCAD LT 2009 installed. I searched through the net for a solution but couldn't find any. So could you help me fix this issue?

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Code taken from @Tom Haws' [blog](http://tomsthird.blogspot.com/2009/04/autocad-customization-search-to-replace.html).

Comment: Hey!  :-)  Is that AutoCAD-Python connection code from my blog?  Cool!

Comment: as far as i can remember, yes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AutoCAD **LT** versions doesn't support automation ([discussion in Autodesk group](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-LT/AutoCAD-LT-2007-usage-via-OLE-Automation/td-p/1797293)).

If you'll be able to install full AutoCAD version, I'd suggest you to use [`comtypes`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) package. With `win32com` you can't add entities to document, because  AutoCAD requires VARIANTs with the typecodes `VT_ARRAY | VT_I2 or VT_ARRAY | VT_R8` for parameters, e.g. `InsertionPoint`.

See [examples in `comtypes` documentation](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/)

Comment: If this works, it's totally awesome.  I hope to try it and report.

Comment: Actually, win32com does work (with Acad2010), but it did take some extra work. The VARIANTs do cause the problem, but not because win32com doesn't know how to handle them. The problem (in my case) was with makepy/genpy defining all the *insert* proxies incorrectly (which I painstakingly corrected by hand). It turns out that AutoCAD expected a VARIANT_ARRAY of VARIANTS, but makepy was not defining the somewhat redundant outer VARIANT_ARRAY, only the array of typed variants. Once I wrapped all function arguments with extra array, INSERT ENTITY worked just great!